# Contact form pushes navigation over the place

Tags: html, css

As you can see here: http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/contact.html < my code is all over the place and I don't know how to fix it. The other pages are okay.

This is my HTML for the contact form:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <h2>Neem contact op</h2>
        <span class="required_notification">* Verplicht in te vullen</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="name">Naam:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Harry Potter" />

    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="harry_potter@flyingowl.com" />
        <span class="form_hint">Goed formaat "harry@voldemortsucks.com"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="website">Website:</label>
        <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="http://voldemortsucks.com/" />
        <span class="form_hint">Goed formaat "http://dumbledoresarmy.com"</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="message">Bericht:</label>
        <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my CSS:

```
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: grey;

}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: grey;
}

*:focus {outline: none;}

body {
    font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
}

.contact_form h2, .contact_form label {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}

.form_hint, .required_notification {font-size: 11px;}

ul {
    width: 750px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    float: right;

}

li {
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}

li:first-child, li:last-child {
    border-bottom:1px solid #777;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    color: white;
}

.required_notification {
    color: #d45252;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}

label {
    width: 150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
}

input {
    height: 20px;
    width: 220px;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
    border-radius:2px;
}

textarea {
    padding: 8px; 
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
    border-radius:2px;
}
button {margin-left: 156px;}

button.submit {
    background-color: white;

}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring css for this `ul` without giving it an `id` or `class`. Give it a class, like the code below:

```
<ul class="contactForm">
  <li>
    <h2>Neem contact op</h2>
    <span class="required_notification">* Verplicht in te vullen</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Naam:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Harry Potter"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="harry_potter@flyingowl.com"/>
    <span class="form_hint">Goed formaat "harry@voldemortsucks.com"</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="website">Website:</label>
    <input type="text" name="website" placeholder="http://voldemortsucks.com/"/>
    <span class="form_hint">Goed formaat "http://dumbledoresarmy.com"</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="message">Bericht:</label>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="6"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="submit" type="submit">Verstuur</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And your css CSS:

```
:-moz-placeholder {
    color: grey;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: grey;
}
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    font: 14px/21px "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", sans-serif;
}
.contact_form h2, .contact_form label {font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
.form_hint, .required_notification{
    font-size: 11px;
}
ul.contactForm {
    width: 750px;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    float: right;
}
ul.contactForm li {
    padding: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You just saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by removing the css from the ul element.
Like the width and float: right;

Answer (score 0):

Your main css is not include in this page please check
and add this css in your contact page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
```

Comment: Got that, I just didn't include it here.

Comment: and remove conflict code in this css http://st358373.cmd16c.cmi.hanze.nl/css/stylesheet8.css

Answer (score 0):

Replace `margin-top` for `padding-top` in your `.titel` class:

```
.titel {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Never give CSS to ul or li, use a class to do so. You have used css on ul, li directly which is affecting at every place..
2. Divide the page in the different segment, you can write menu section in a separate file and can include in all pages.

**Why you have added margin to body?**

```
body {
 margin: 8px; // remove it.
}
```

**Why you have added a div in contact menu?**

remove it

You can use @kittyCat form design and css.

Implement this, and then know me if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks! It's slowly starting to become familiar.